# How to execute a system command on a remote Linux server using CGI and Perl's Net::OpenSSH module?

Tags: linux, perl, ssh

EDIT: Read this first: What I was trying to do here is the result of extreme tunnel visioning, the post might be amusing, but not informative. You don't need to SSH into your own server to execute a command, what was I even thinking...

the title pretty much says it all. I want to host a CGI website on a Linux server (Debian, if it matters) and when clicking a button, perform a system command on the server itself. I'm doing this through Perl and it's `Net::OpenSSH` module.

Here is the problem. I can run the script through the terminal on the server itself, but *only* if I use sudo. It doesn't matter if the command is simply "`ls`". Unsurprisingly, when clicking on a button on a website which calls the module, it doesn't work either.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::OpenSSH;

print("Content-type: text/html\n\n");

print("TEST");

my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new('localhost', user => 'myusername', password => 'mypassword');

$ssh->system("ls") or die "ERROR: " . $ssh->error;

print("TEST2");
```

When running it in the terminal using sudo, the script prints out `TEST`, then lists the folders in my home directory (Desktop, Documents, etc) and finally, `TEST2`.

When I'm not using sudo, it prints only `TEST` and after that this error message:

> ERROR: unable to establish master SSH connection: the authenticity of
>   the target host can't be established; the remote host public key is
>   probably not present on the '~/.shh/known_hosts' file at
>   opensshtest.pl line 13.

I'm not using SSH keys at all, I'm trying to supply the username and password by hardcoding them into the script.

Also, when opened in a browser, it only prints out the first `TEST`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I forgot to add this: it says that the error is on line 13. It's actually line 12, since this code doesn't have another line which is originally commented out.

Comment: I'm confused. Why is ssh involved here?

Comment: Actually, that's a very good question. The answer is; my state of confusion and googling skills led me to that. I remember starting with Perl's `exec();` function, not having any success, and the rest is blurry. But hey, I've made it work, see below if you're interested.

Comment: [`perldoc -f exec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html): "The exec function executes a system command *and never returns*; use system instead of exec if you want it to return."

Comment: That might actually be the problem. IIRC, when running the CGI from a browser, it would just hang, as if it's having trouble loading the site. Talk about a roundabout way of using ssh... Thanks for pointing that out, I'll try it again using `system();`.

Answer (score 0):

It's me again, the guy who posted the question. It's funny how I've spent hours trying to make this work, and stumbled upon a solution maybe an hour after posting the question here. But here it is:

I've added `master_opts => [-o => "StrictKeyChecking=no"]` as an additional argument to the creation of the Net::OpenSSH object (the line with `user`, `password`, etc).

Comment: Oh, and by the way, I removed that line after running the code once and it still works. Running the code with that line has done some SSH key black magic on the server (I'm still very new to this).

Comment: The section [TROUBLESHOOTING](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH#TROUBLESHOOTING) from the module docs, tries to explain that, specifically point [3](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH#run-ssh-from-the-command-line).